# How to change slide on selected option in caroufredsel

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, caroufredsel

i have code for slider and i m using caroufredsel. I need to change slide on selected dropdown and also to stop auto slide.

Here is code for slider.

```
<div class="carousel">
                    <div class="slider">
                        <img src="images/image1.jpg" class="slider-image-1"/>
                        <div class="slider-text">
                            <h3>Heading 1</h3>
                            <p>Paragraph 1</p>
                            <p>Paragraph 2</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="image-in-slide">
                            <img src="images/image-in-slide1.png"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slider">
                        <img src="images/image1.jpg" class="slider-image-2"/>
                        <div class="slider-text">
                            <h3>Heading 1</h3>
                            <p>Paragraph 1</p>
                            <p>Paragraph 2</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="image-in-slide">
                            <img src="images/image-in-slide2.png"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

And here is what i got in jquery

```
$("#dropdown1").change(function() {
        var select_value = $("option:selected", "#dropdown1").val();

        switch (select_value) {
            case "1":
                $(".carousel").trigger("configuration", {auto: false} );
                break;
            case "2":
                $(".carousel").trigger("configuration", {auto: false});
                break;
            case "3":
                $(".carousel").trigger("configuration", {auto: false});
                break;
            case "4":
                $(".carousel").trigger("configuration", {auto: false});
                break;
            case "5":
                $(".carousel").trigger("configuration", {auto: false});
                break;
            case "6":
                $(".carousel").trigger("configuration", {auto: false});
                break;
        }
    });
```

This function here work for stoping slide, but i don't know how to show slide when i select an option.

Any help, please.

Thank you.